# Discrete Random variables, 2 balls chosen from 8 white, 4 black and 2 orange

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

i've just finished Chapter 4 of "a first course in probability 8th edition" which deals with defining Discrete Random Variables, calculating the Expectation and Variance, and gives a bit of background knowledge on common discrete random variables (the Binomial, poisson, geometric, negative binomial and hypergeometric).

my issue is the first question of the problem sheet. it goes as follows

> Two balls are chosen randomly from an urn containing
>   8 white, 4 black, and 2 orange balls. Suppose
>   that we win \$2 for each black ball selected and we lose \$1 for each white ball selected. Let X denote our winnings. What are the possible values
>   of X, and what are the probabilities associated with each value?

now, ive correctly determined the possible values of X and the probabilities but i feel like i was ment to utilise one of the distributions that i had just learnt about. but i couldnt figure out how as X is winnings rather than balls selected (otherwise i'd probably have used the hypergeometric distribution)

rather than my way which is as follows

---

we have a maximum winnings of \$4, denoted by 2 black, and a minimum of \$-2. this means that X takes values $-2,-1,0,1,2,4$ and these represent either picking 2 black balls or 1 black ball and any other ball. 2 orange balls, 2 white balls and finally 1 white ball and any other ball.

this leaves me with

$$P(X=4)=\frac{4 \cdot 3}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{6}{91}$$
$$P(X=2)=\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{8}{91}$$
$$P(X=1)=\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 8}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{32}{91}$$
$$P(X=0)=\frac{ 2 \cdot 1}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{1}{91}$$
$$P(X=-1)=\frac{2 \cdot 8 \cdot 2}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{16}{91}$$
$$P(X=-2)=\frac{8 \cdot 7}{14 \cdot 13} = \frac{28}{91}$$

---

so my question is. was there another method to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that you are selecting without replacement.  You can use the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: to use the hypergeometric wouldnt i have to define a 3 new random variable to be the probability of picking one of the three colours respectively? ie Let $Y= \# ~ black ~ balls$

then $$Y \sim HyperGeo(2,14,4) $$
$$y(i)=\frac{{{4}\choose{i}}{{10}\choose{2-i}}}{{{14}\choose{2}}}$$

then do something similiar for White and orange, then to find the probability of X (the winnings) would be combinations of these three random variables?

or am i over-complicating this?

Comment: Multivariate Hypergeometric: The probability distribution for selecting $B$ black balls and $W$ white balls is given by: $~\mathsf P(B=b,W=w) = \dfrac{\binom 4b \binom 2w \binom 8{2-b-w}}{\binom {14}2} \mathbf 1_{0\leq b, 0\leq w, b+w\leq 2}$ .  Which is what was used above.

Comment: ahhhh i see, see i've yet to learn about multivariate hyperogeometric it appears to have just been co-incidence that i used it. (though in all honesty it was just a simplification of the different orders of drawing the ball) does that mean theres not really any other way of doing this only using the the Binomial, poisson, geometric, negative binomial and hypergeometric? (single variable versions)

Comment: The problem should say that balls are chosen without replacement. I verified your six probabilities (+1) by simulating a million draws of 2 balls and tallying the results. [If simulation is _with_ replacement, then the distribution is 'multinomial'.]